# How can I use my xbox 360 controller on my pc?

Tags: windows, xbox360, game-controller

I have read about it online people using their controller for pc games and other things, how can i do this?

Comment: Is this a wired or wireless 360 Controller?

Comment: wired controller

Answer (score 8):

The Xbox 360 controller uses a regular USB 2.0 connector. The only thing you are missing is the software. Microsoft has an article titled [**How to connect your Xbox 360 Controller for Windows to your computer**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906347).

In summary:

- Download controller software for your operating system [**here**](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/download/download.aspx?category=Gaming).
- Plug in your controller to a USB 2.0 slot.

Make sure they are done in that order, the controller isn't supposed to be connected while the software installs.

Comment: Normally Windows should automatically detect and install the appropriate software when you first plug it in. This has always worked for me, though I can't remember if I ever tried it on XP.

Comment: The http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906347 link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

once you have it installed, you may want to read this:

**[Configuring Your Xbox 360 Controller For Windows](http://mattbrett.com/2005/11/configuring-your-xbox-360-controller-for-windows/)**